# Rate Module - Ability to "Rate" people

Tags: rating

Using the [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) Module , I'm interested to know if it is possible to "Rate" people.

For example, rate a *tradesman*; rate a *private tutors teaching service*; rate any *service provider*.

I'm already using the [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module for node rating, but cannot seem to find at this moment the ability for the above, unless it's custom hack or something.

Has anyone used the Rate module for similar, or would anyone like to share a general overview of what's needed to accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal is very capable in this arena.

A few modules that come to mind are:

- [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi)
- [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar)
- [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate)

With more detail I think you would get a better answer, but at a glance I believe you could accomplish this quite easily with readily available modules.

The tricky part I believe will be figuring out how to structure your site.

Will People/Service providers be stored as nodes or user accounts?

Will users need to register to rate? Can anonymous users rate? Both?

Can service providers register their own business/service or will you be adding a pre-selected list?

---

If you create a custom content type called "Service Provider" for example, you could apply the Rate module to this content type and have something up and running quite quickly.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using Voting API and Rate (I dismissed Fivestar after trying as IMO, Rate is best). I already have 'provider' details in Profile2 format but they are also 'user' accounts as they link inot Ubercart for subscriptions as they WILL be registering a business to offer a service. I never thought of creating a further custom content node such as 'service provider', but that sounds like a good idea, so I'll pursue that avenue. My stumbling block was that I cannot see the Rate element in any user profile, hence my question are if/how it can be done. I'm using Rules/Views etc. (-:

Comment: The Rate module is awesome for sure, but the Fivestar module uses fields at its core.  Now that Users are fieldable (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) it may be worth revisiting.

Comment: All services providers can post content relevant to their service' wants' and completed 'consumers' may want to leave a 'rating' on the serives provided by the service provider (ie, homeowner (service wanted user type) wants gardener wanted to cut grass; Rate: 5/10 for good job rated along with good feedback text on Gardeners profile (Service provider user type). It's a common thing as you see, but at this moment, I cannot see what plugs in where; I've come far, but so far to go! (-;

Comment: Thank you CitricGuy. Arh, FiveStar, I did have it installed at first, then uninstalled the module in favour of Rate. Your advice could well be the direction. I'm curious then if both modules will work in at the same time? for 2 different functions as per required above, as I really like the rate Thumbs Up/Down etc. Worth a try, if they don't conflict. But more to manage IMO.

Comment: They shouldn't conflict at all.  I can absolutely see using both on a single project as well.  The FIvestar module also has a much larger user base. Roughly 4.5x larger.  Fivestar's issue queue also seems to be much more active.

Comment: That's interesting Citricguy that they may both work on the same site. In that case I may be able to use the Fivestar for rating User Accounts and Rate for Content Nodes, if the need arises for both. I'll come back here and feedback for future readers on how things panned out with my requirements and any troubles I incurred. Thanks again, for your time. Good karma to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and aggregation in views to have the counting of flags using `Flag:flagged (A boolean field to show whether the flag is set or not)` as a view field, you will need to add the flag as a relationship for that. Then in the view field: aggregation `count distinct` => nb of flags on a user. You can even have different countings or flags (customer services, delivery time, etc.) by user.